# how to get key value from jquery auto complete

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, autocomplete

This is my html:

```
<div class="ui-widget col-lg-6 ">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input name="parent_id" class="form-control" type="text" id="parent_id">    
</div>                
</div>
```

this is my Array which I m using to get value form database. I fetching id and name. But when I submit data, it is passing name instead of id. How can I submit key value i.e. id. I am using cakephp 3.x.  This is my controller function.

```
 public function availableMembers() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if (!empty($this->request->query)) {
            $table = TableRegistry::get('FamilyMembers');
            $list = $table->find()->where(['first_name LIKE'=>'%'.$this->request->query['term'].'%'])->toArray();
            $arrList = array();
            foreach ($list as $row) {
            $arrList[$row['id']] = $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];
            }    
        }
        echo json_encode($arrList);
        exit;
    }
```

This is my script:

```
<script> 
  $( function() {
    $( "#parent_id" ).autocomplete({
      source: '/app/availableMembers',
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get jQuery autocomplete work your php should return a json object with 2 property: "value" and "label".
So you need something like this

`$arrList[] = array(
  "label" => $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'],
  "value" => $row['id']
);`

Than in you javascript you should set the id like this

`$( function() {
    $( "#parent_id" ).autocomplete({
      minLength : 2,
      source: '/app/availableMembers',
      select : function(event, ui) {    //when we select something from the dropdown
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        return false;
        },
    });
  } );`